# Async activiti job in sync REST controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, activiti, bpmn

Spring Boot application with Activiti ('org.activiti:activiti-spring-boot-starter:7.1.0.M3.1') has sync REST API for requests from System_A, on the other side there is the System_B with async API for data exchange with our Spring Boot App. All business processes run over activiti engine and interaction scheme is like this:

1. System_A sends sync request to our API and waits response.
2. Our API starts an activiti business process.
3. One of the activiti service tasks sends an async request to System_B API.
4. System_B sends async response to our API and System_A receives response too.

Now between points 3 and 4 I use the next trick to wait async response form System_B API:

1. Set async-executor-activate param to 'true' in application props.
2. Lock thread by Hazelcast - getHazelcastInstance().getLock(...).
3. Start activiti business process - getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey(...).
4. Send async request to System_B API in activiti serviceTask by RestTemplate exchange method.
5. Activate timer for 3 sec and wait for signal (look bpmn fragment below).
   5.1. When timeout, unlock thread in service.end(...) call, then System_A receives sync response.
   5.2. When System_B sends async response, activiti getRuntimeService().signalEventReceived(...) is called, business process is continued and System_A receives sync response after service.end(...) is reached.

```
<signal id="signalReceiveResponse" name="signalReceiveResponse" />

...

<eventBasedGateway id="waitResponseFromSystemB"/>

<sequenceFlow id="flow_waitResponseFromSystemB_waitResponse" sourceRef="waitResponseFromSystemB" targetRef="waitResponse"/>
<intermediateCatchEvent id="waitResponse">
    <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT3S</timeDuration>
    </timerEventDefinition>
</intermediateCatchEvent>

<sequenceFlow id="flow_waitResponseFromSystemB_receiveResponse" sourceRef="waitResponseFromSystemB" targetRef="receiveResponse"/>
<intermediateCatchEvent id="receiveResponse">
    <signalEventDefinition signalRef="signalReceiveResponse" />
</intermediateCatchEvent>

<sequenceFlow id="flow_waitResponse_timeoutRequest" sourceRef="waitResponse" targetRef="timeoutRequest"/>
<serviceTask id="timeoutRequest" activiti:expression="${service.timeout(execution)}"/>

<sequenceFlow id="flow_timeoutRequest_endProcess" sourceRef="timeoutRequest" targetRef="endProcess"/>

<sequenceFlow id="flow_receiveResponse_processResponse" sourceRef="receiveResponse" targetRef="processResponse"/>

...

<endEvent id="endProcess">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="end" expression="${service.end(execution)}"/>
    </extensionElements>
</endEvent>
```

Is there more graceful solutions to wait async response from System_B. Without manual thread locks, entangled eventBasedGateway, async activiti process and signal events?